# Core 2 MVC Can't access wwwroot lib

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am making the switch over to Core 2 from .Net and rather than using templates provided by VS2017 I wanted to create an app from scratch to see the workings. I am however using a template project to check against for when I get stuck but I can't see what is causing the access issue.

The issue I'm getting is when I run the web application, none of the content from `wwwroot/lib` is being accessed. The environment is development, and the links are specified as such within the layout:

`<environment include="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    </environment>`

If I take the links out of the environment element, they still can't be accessed, using fiddler I can see a 404 error but the files are there.

These files are present in the project, installed through `bower` and the files are referenced in the `bower.json` file. The `.bowerrc` file specifies the `wwwroot/lib` as where to store the content.

My `Configure` method in the StartUp is as below:

```
    `public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        // to get cookie authentication to work
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }`
```

What could be causing this restricted access to the `wwwroot/lib` ?

**Edit 1:**

Initially `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` wasn't working from `_ViewImports` but I couldn't see why, bootstrap was working at this point. The only change I made was to add `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` at the top of the layout file, which made all of the `asp-` elements work. However nothing was being access in the `wwwroot/lib`.

No big deal, removed the `@addTag` from the layout, and wwwroot still couldn't be accessed. I've since restarted visual studio, multiple rebuilds and cleans but nothing has worked. Weirdly, since removing `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` from layout, ViewImports is working I think as the `asp-` helpers still function.

**Edit 2:**

I have published to a remote IIS server and it is running with the correct content no problem. With this in mind I have installed IIS on my local machine, instead of IIS Express. When I run this in debug it still isn't picking up the correct content.

**Edit 3:**

Not sure why or how but `_ViewImports.cshtml` appears to be the issue. If I remove it, the application picks up the styling, however I still cannot access the `.css.` or `.js` files through the browser. The browser console also reports errors that the content cannot be accessed, so how it's picking up the styling is a bit confusing!

Comment: This is actually added by the `UseStaticFiles()` function. Are you sure you cleaned and compiled after adding that function?

Comment: More info on this folder here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files

Comment: @NevilleNazerane - yes I've clean and rebuilt numerous times. That's the function I thought was responsible for doing it. However it's stopped working when I added `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` into the layout when _ViewImports wasn't working. Then the asp- elements began working so I removed from the _Layout but I now cannot access the lib. Maybe restarting VS/PC will fix it...

Comment: you have already tried localhost:8080/css/site.css right?

Comment: Yes, can't get there, Page can't be found. Apologies just tried restarting VS, didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: You can also try running from console in case it really is VS. `dotnet clean` `dotnet build` `dotnet run`

Comment: @MayankGaur sorry, no, I'm not working on that project anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution as such, I had to start a new project and copied the contents of the files across and it worked. The only difference to the project set up was files like `_ViewImports.cshtml` I added using the specific file, not renaming a view. It looks identical so I don't know if there are behind the scenes reasons for this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
In my case it was related to permissions under wwwroot folder.
What worked for me was: 
**Right Click on wwwroot folder in Windows Explorer => Properties => Uncheck Read Only**

Answer (score 0):

My issues was that the files were ignored via Source Control as I added them via Visual Studio 'Client Side Library' helper. Visual Studio showed a little red icon on the file in the solution explorer as opposed to blue padlock (I just happened to miss this).

I right clicked on the lib folder and 'Add Ignored File(s) to Source Control'.